# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket not found by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've made multiple attempts to try to connect to MSSQL from a JSP but cannot get around the error produced when I try to initiate the actual connection. The JAR has been wrapped as an OSGi bundle with all of the dependencies resolved on a 1.8 JVM. Interestingly enough, the exact same JSP code will run perfectly on a Mac platform but not when deployed to the production Windows 2012 server.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket not found by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver [587]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 160 more

Answer (score 0):

Normally `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket` will be loaded from `rt.jar` in the boot classpath.  What JSP container are you using, and how have you configured the boot classpath for it?  You mentioned that you have this working on OSX: what configuration differences exist between that environment and Windows?

Comment: I'm using Adobe AEM 6.2 as the deployment engine. Between the two machines the JRE is identical but the MSSQL server on the Mac machine is running locally (VM) and on the Windows server the MSSQL server is remote.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here for wrapping the JDBC driver in an OSGi bundle?  https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/jdbc.html

Comment: Yes, the OSGi bundle is wrapped properly and actively deployed.

Comment: It appears then that your bundle isn't importing the `javax.net.ssl` package.  Can you confirm this by inspecting the driver bundle `MANIFEST.MF` file?

Comment: Yes,  includes javax.net.ssl.

Comment: Hi @Lee, were you able to fix this issue ? I am seeing the same error in my AEM 6.2 application